# APEX-created master detail form., Created header and unable to add line details

Tags: oracle-apex

I got below error, how can i reolve it? Some please help me to fix this issue.

Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - Attempt to save item P22_ORDER_RELEASE_GID in session state during show processing. Item protection level indicates: Item may be set when accompanied by a "session" checksum. No checksum was passed in or the checksum passed in would be suitable for an item with protection level "(No checksum was provided)". Note: End users get a different error message. - Contact your application administrator. for ajax_set_session_state.

I have create master-detail report with auto populate P22_ORDER_RELEASE_GID based to order type.
I could able to create order. But will adding it I'm getting above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well... the error says exactly what is going on. Item `P22_ORDER_RELEASE_GID` cannot be set because the security settings (Page item attributes > Security > Session State Protection) are set to "Checksum Required" and no checksum is provided when the page item is being set in your page.
The setting "Checksum Required" should be used when an id is being passed as part of a url (branch to another page, redirect, etc). When setting an item value within a page in some other way (I don't know what you mean by "with auto populate P22_ORDER_RELEASE_GID"), the checksum cannot be calculated and this error is raised.
Solution: set "Page item attributes > Security > Session State Protection" to "unrestricted"

Comment: I got it, thanks.